# Node.js child process как ограничить выделяемую память

Tags: javascript, node.js

Можно ли как-то средствами node.js ограничить выделяемую память для `child_process`? Нужно сделать `ulimit -m X`, при этом если память превышает X, то нужно кинуть ошибку. Как это реализовать? Можно ли сделать это встроенными методами в node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте параметр "–max-old-space-size" 
node –max-old-space-size=6000 indiex.js

Comment: Мне нужно ограничить процесс только child_process, при этом память я выделяю не константную.